# I want to run this procedure in sas9.1

Tags: sas

I want to run this procedure in sas9.1:

```
proc     ttest      data=auc     dist=lognormal     tost(0.8, 1.25);     
      paired     TestAUC*RefAUC;     
run;
```

but it had an error!

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Any chance you could actually tell us what the error was?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to compare area under the curve (auc) from two roc curves. This link may help you: 
http://support.sas.com/kb/45/339.html

It uses a chi-square test, but it may be more appropriate than a t-test. It's hard to tell with the limited information  you have provided.